# How to convert a C#8 switch expression to a classic switch?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, .net-4.5, c#-5.0, c#-8.0

Could anyone help me to convert the below expression to a classic switch since i can't use it?

```
private static bool TryGetScaleTransform(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, out ScaleTransform scaleTransform)
    {
        scaleTransform = frameworkElement.LayoutTransform switch
        {
            TransformGroup transformGroup => transformGroup.Children.OfType<ScaleTransform>().FirstOrDefault(),
            ScaleTransform transform => transform,
            _ => null
        };

        return scaleTransform != null;
    }
```

Comment: What's the motivation?  Curious why you want a switch statement instead of an expression

Comment: So you want to convert the [C# 8 switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions) to a classic switch? @Jonesopolis: Motivation could be: he cannot use it or he doesn't understand it.

Comment: What do you think it should be?

Comment: Because I am using C# 4.5. For switch expression it needs C# 8.0

Comment: No, you can use C#8 in .NET 4.5 with the `<LangVersion>latest<LangVersion>` tag in csproj. See: [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version). Don't confuse C# and .NET version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind it is almost the same as what you have written. Here is the syntax for C# 7:

```cs
private static bool TryGetScaleTransform(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, out ScaleTransform scaleTransform)
{
    switch(frameworkElement.LayoutTransform)
    {
        case TransformGroup transformGroup:
            scaleTransform= transformGroup.Children
                .OfType<ScaleTransform>().FirstOrDefault();
            break;
        case ScaleTransform transform:
            scaleTransform = transform;
            break;
        default:
            scaleTransform = null;
            break;
    }

    return scaleTransform != null;
}
```

The above solution needs C# 7 to work. If you are using a language version below that, you have to contend yourself with `if - else`.

```cs
private static bool TryGetScaleTransform(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, out ScaleTransform scaleTransform)
{
    if(frameworkElement.LayoutTransform is TransformGroup)
    {
        scaleTransform = frameworkElement.LayoutTransform.Children
            .OfType<ScaleTransform>().FirstOrDefault();
        return true;
    }

    if(frameworkElement.LayoutTransform is ScaleTransform)
    {
         scaleTransform = frameworkElement.LayoutTransform;
         return true;
    }

    scaleTransform null;
    return false;
}
```